# Setting up a microsoft access database connection with node.js

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, pdo, ms-access-2010

Hy guys,

I recently started looking into node.js, and I decided to rewrite all the php code to javascript code. That all went well, but now I'm trying to set up a database connection to a microsoft access database. I tried doing something like this:

`var dbname = "/databases/users.accdb";
var db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" + dbname + ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=;");`

But that doesn't seem to work, since it gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: PDO is not defined` error.

How would i do this properly?

Sincerely, Zeno

EDIT: I have set the environment PYTHON variable, downloaded microsoft visual studio 2012, and when I install the odbc module, 300+ error lines are produced. too much to list here obviously, i can't even see the top of the error log in the console... Anyone has an idea what's going on?

Answer (score -1):

Select a database library from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/), [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally) it, and then follow the documentation for it instead of trying to use [PHP code](http://php.net/pdo) in the middle of a JavaScript program.

Comment: do you recommend something? the odbc module seemed interesting, but when I install it, it gives me all kinds of errors, which state that the problem lays with the package, not with npm itself.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic for Stackoverflow. You might want to ask a question about interpreting the "all kinds of errors" (which likely have a single root cause that the first error message will reveal).

Comment: okay, the error is: "Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTON env variable."

Comment: So have you installed Python?

Comment: yes I did, from the website https://www.python.org/downloads/. But it still throws the error.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to do that -_- . anyway, now it throws me an error that it can't find a .net framework, so I am installing that right now.